# Call() method fails to generate output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript from udemy and in one lecture tutor has implemented a function using `bind()` method, however when i am trying to use `call()` it doesn't work.

Here is a small program that works with bind:

```
function mapForEach(arr, fn){
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        newArr.push(
            fn(arr[i])
        )
    };

    return newArr;
}

var arr1 = [1,2,3];

/* trying to compare if the item is greater than given limiter*/
var checkPastLimit = function(limiter, item){
    return item > limiter;
}

/*bind both functions and check if item is greater than 1*/
var arr4 = mapForEach(arr1, checkPastLimit.bind(this,1));
/*print array in boolean*/
console.log(arr4); 

-----
Output: [false,true,true]
```

This program works as I want, however how can i use `call()` or `apply()` method here instead of bind? I am trying from yesterday but not getting what i want.

**What I tried**

I tried following documentation on [mozilla's offical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) page, however I don't get the desired output.

I tried editing the `checkPastLimit` function like below:

```
var checkPastLimit = function(limiter, item){
    mapForEach.call(arr1, checkPastLimit(this,1));
    return item > limiter;
}

console.log(checkPastLimit);
```

but this code throws recursion problem.

I also tried another trick but it didnt worked too

```
var checkPastLimit = function(limiter, item){
    return item > limiter;
}

mapForEach.call(arr1, checkPastLimit(this,1));
```

**What I Want**

The working program listed above generates the desired output using `bind()`, but i want to get the output using `call()`

`[false,true,true]` //if 1 is limiter

`[false,false,true]` // if 2 is limiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` and `call` (or `apply`) are not really alternatives for the same thing. `bind` returns a function, while `call` executes a function. The only thing they have in common is that they allow to specify what `this` should be. But in your actual case the value of `this` is not used, so that common part is not relevant.

In your working code the `bind` method is used to create a *curried* function on-the-fly, i.e. it creates a new function that takes one argument less, since the first argument is fixed to be the value 1. This is called *currying*.

If you want to do this without `bind` then you really are going to implement your own version of `bind` (specific to this case). It could for instance look like this:

```
// Create this additional function, which returns a function(!) with one less argument.
var curriedCheckPastLimit = function (limiter) {
    return function(item) {
        return checkPastLimit(limiter, item);
    }
}

var arr4 = mapForEach(arr1, curriedCheckPastLimit(1)); // No more bind!
```

Or you could drop the currying pattern and just do this (using an arrow function with expression syntax):

```
var arr4 = mapForEach(arr1, item => checkPastLimit(1, item));
```

As a side note: your `mapForEach` function already exists as a native array method:

```
var arr4 = arr1.map(item => checkPastLimit(1, item));
```

Comment: your solution works but its little difficult to digest as a beginner. so as far as i understood i can only execute it using bind currying method or no bind. This is very confusing but thanks i am trying to understand it.

Comment: Let me know how I can help. I agree that currying is not beginner's stuff.

Comment: i tried this program in ide and slowly tried to understand what this is doing. because there is a function returning a function which is returning another function, it looks so confusing. but i am getting it little by little. just trying to connect all the dots, however i shall accept your answer. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The function `mapForEach` accepts a function as second parameter.

When you call `checkPastLimit.bind(this,1)` it returns a function as result.

When you call `checkPastLimit.call(this,1)` it returns false.

So you can't simply use `call` instead of `bind`

[image]

Comment: yes i understood that. as per comment above it seems i cannot use call just as i used bind